# Invalid expression term '.', method "invoke"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm using visual studio 2010 and .net framework version 4, I know that this question was asked before and the solution was to change .net framewwork, I installed .net4.7 but visual studio accepts only .net4.

```cs
   public void callback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
            try
            {
                sck.EndReceive(ar);
                byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
                int rec = sck.Receive(buf, buf.Length, 0);
                if (rec < buf.Length)
                {
                    Array.Resize<byte>(ref buf, rec);
                }
                Received?.Invoke(this, buf);//ERROR HERE
                sck.BeginReceive(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 0, 0, callback, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                close();
                Disconnected?.Invoke(this);//ERROR HERE 
            }
        }

// recieved and disconnected
  public delegate void ClientReceivedHandler(Client_Connexion sender, byte[] data);
        public delegate void ClientDisconnectedHandler(Client_Connexion sender);
        public event ClientReceivedHandler Received;
        public event ClientDisconnectedHandler Disconnected;
```

In my code where I get an error for `Received?.Invoke`

> Invalid expression term '.'
>
> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Is there any suggestion to change `Received?.Invoke` with an other form?

I tried `Received != null ? Received.Invoke: null;` but the problem wasn't solved.

Comment: I suspect that you're using a C# version before 6.0 (AFAIK that's where the null conditional operators were introduced). Does a simpler use of these compile? I'd use a simple `if(Received != null) Received.Invoke(this, buf);` if these are unavailable.

Comment: ad what is `Received` and `Disconnected`

Comment: "and the solution was to change .net framewwork," No, it´s changing the **language**-version, which depends on the version of VS.

Comment: @HimBromBeere how to change ***language-version** * ?

Comment: @Selvin I added them in code now.

Comment: @ManelHkiri You need VS2015, VS2010 died 9 years ago

Comment: By changing the VS-version. As this isn´t possible for ou, you simply can´t use this language-feature and stay with the old syntax as shown in cantons answer.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto in reality this problem is for my friend, I'm using vs2015, but she uses vs2010 she tried to install v2015 but she couldn't (os is Windows 7)

Comment: @ManelHkiri What? Windows 7 is completely supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2015-sysrequirements-vs

Comment: There's no reason you can't install VS2015 on Windows 7. Also, VS2019 came out yesterday, nobody really wants to stick with such an old product, especially in the world of software dev where things move so quickly.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, even VS2019 supports Windows 7: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements

Comment: I don't know why but she gets many errors each time she try to install it!

Comment: Maybe the question you should be asking is how to solve the errors she encounters...

Comment: That's an altogether different problem. "many errors" doesn't mean much, if anything at all. Look at the SP1 update required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null-conditional operator (`?.`) was introduced in C# 6. Visual Studio 2010 only supports C# 4. You'll need Visual Studio 2015 or higher: you're limited by your Visual Studio version, not by your .NET version.

You'll have to use the old pattern for raising events:

```
var handler = Received; // The temporary copy is very important to avoid race conditions
if (handler != null)
{
    handler(this, buf);
}
```

Comment: Just saw that in the linked answer - updated.

Comment: thank you that's solved the last error, but now we have an other " LanmanWorkstation  service cannot be started" , we are working on it, thank you all.